# Prove that diagonally dominant matrices are regular - Reference request

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, online-resources, gershgorin-sets

I know that it is easy to prove that diagonally dominant matrices are regular (non-singular) by the gershgorin circle theorem. But the theorem that diagonally dominant matrices are regular was discovered earlier, e.g. by Minkowski in 1900, so am looking for one of those *original* proofs.

Can you help me to find this one? Is there any free eBook or skript? 
Also, I am *not* looking for the proof by Levy who proved this for real matrices only, but another proof e.g. by Desplanques would be nice to see as well.

Comment: *Regular* means *non-singular*?

Comment: @GitGud yes, it does

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that this is not the complete answer, but I found in Matrix Iterative Analysis by Varga this (see item 1.5 in Bibliography and Discussion section of Chapter 1):

> That strictly or irreducibly diagonally dominant matrices are necessarily nonsingular is a result which many have discovered independently. Taussky (1949) has collected a long list of contributors to this result and is an excellent reference for related material.

Reference:

O. Taussky, A recurring theorem on determinants. *Amer. Math. Monthly* **56**, 672--676, 1949.

I don't have access there but it seems that the paper is accessible via JStor.

Answer (score 1):

The proof by **Minkowski** can be found in [this](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=GDZPPN002498723&IDDOC=191772) paper

**BibTeX**:

```
@article{Minkowski1900,
author = {Minkowski, Hermann},
journal = {Nachrichten von der Gesellschaft der Wissenschaften zu Göttingen, Mathematisch-Physikalische Klasse},
keywords = {Minkowski's determinant theorem; Minkowski unit},
language = {ger},
pages = {90-93},
title = {Zur Theorie der Einheiten in den algebraischen Zahlkörpern},
url = {http://eudml.org/doc/58467},
volume = {1900},
year = {1900},
}
```